# connecting my application to wamp server

Tags: android

I am new to android. I want to display my localhost (wampserver) Page on a click of a button.

I have tried using `httppost` method but it is not displaying anything just a blank mess. If I give a wrong addres then it is throwing error message.

All help is appriciated

Comment: Similar are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905315/error-connection-refused/4905367#4905367) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721281/im-unable-to-call-a-servlet-from-my-android-application/4721383#4721383)

Answer (score 3):

use `10.0.2.2` instead of `localhost` in your URLs which you're directing towards your wamp

check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#localhostalias) out.

Comment: Is it working via a web browser? how do u make sure that it isn't working, by the way?